Error in DAML test file - "Could not find module"
I am new to DAML. This is my first project setting it up and I am running into the below issue. Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.
I am using VS code and have created a daml project in it using "daml new" command. This is my directory structure. This is just a small personal project to learn the working of daml. So, I am okay with sharing these codes.
loan-approval-system
->src/
->test/
->daml.yaml

These are the files in the src directory
Loan.daml
module Loan where

template Loan
  with
    borrower: Party
    bank: Party
    amount: Decimal
  where
    signatory borrower, bank

LoanApproval.daml
module LoanApproval where

template LoanRequest
  with
    borrower: Party
    bank: Party
    amount: Decimal
  where
    signatory borrower
    observer bank

    choice ApproveRequest : ContractId Loan
      with
        bankApproval: Party
      controller bank
      do
        -- Ensure that only the bank can approve the request
        assertMsg "Bank approval required" (bankApproval == bank)
        
        -- Create a new Loan contract
        loanCid <- create Loan with
          borrower = borrower
          bank = bank
          amount = amount

        -- Archive the LoanRequest contract
        archive self

        -- Return the new Loan contract ID
        return loanCid

template Loan
  with
    borrower: Party
    bank: Party
    amount: Decimal
  where
    signatory borrower, bank

Main.daml
module Main where

import Daml.Script

-- Define an empty script for now
setup : Script ()
setup = return ()

These are my test and yaml files.
daml.yaml
# for config file options, refer to
# https://docs.daml.com/tools/assistant.html#project-config-file-daml-yaml

sdk-version: 2.9.4
name: loan-approval-system
source: src
modules:
  - LoanApproval
init-script: Main:setup
version: 0.0.1
dependencies:
  - daml-prim
  - daml-stdlib
  - daml-script

test/LoanApprovalTest.daml
module LoanApprovalTest where

import Daml.Script
import LoanApproval

test : Scenario ()
test = do
  -- Create parties
  borrower <- allocateParty "Borrower"
  bank <- allocateParty "Bank"

  -- Create LoanRequest
  requestCid <- submit borrower do
    create LoanRequest with
      borrower = borrower
      bank = bank
      amount = 1000.0

  -- Approve LoanRequest
  submit bank do
    exercise requestCid ApproveRequest with
      bankApproval = bank

  return ()

The test file has an issue in "import LoanApproval" line. It says
"Could not find module `LoanApproval'
It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package."
Right now, I don't think the test is even executing. I am expecting the test to execute without any errors. Am I missing something in the yaml file?

In VS Code, use File -> Open Folder and then select the folder that has the daml.yaml file.
Alternatively, from the command line, the sequence would be something like this:
daml new loan-approval-system

cd loan-approval-system

daml studio

In your example, you should open loan-approval-system, not its parent. That is, you should not see loan-approval-system in VS Code's Explorer window. You should see src, test, and daml.yaml.

Hi Wallace, thanks for your response. Indeed, I had created it using the steps you mentioned. My "loan-approval-system" folder has the daml.yaml file inside it and that's what is open in my VS code. Do you know any other reason this issue occurs?
